# How to format to input date, month, year separate on MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

Hope you ok expert!!
I just want to know whats wrong with my table, I created table 'table1' by using php with the following instruction.

```
<?php
        // use mysql connect

    $num="create table table1
     (student_id int primary key NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
       name varchar (10) NOT NULL,
          math varchar (20) NOT NULL,
          english varchar (10) NOT NULL,
     date DATE,
      month DATE,
         year DATE )";


   mysql_query($num,$con);
     mysql_close($con);
        ?>
```

My question is why? when am input date,month,year it show something like this

```
    student_id name   math  english date       month        year
    1          simon  100   100     0000-00-00  0000-00-00  0000-00-00
```

And I expect this to be

```
    student_id name   math  english date  month   year
    1          simon  100   100     1     March   2013
```

Like this may be.

```
    <?php
    // use mysql connect

$num="create table table1
 (student_id int primary key NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   name varchar (10) NOT NULL,
      math varchar (20) NOT NULL,
      english varchar (10) NOT NULL,
 date DATE strtotime,
  month DATE strtotime,
     year DATE strtotime)";


         mysql_query($num,$con);
                mysql_close($con);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you told it to store a date?

Dates are stored in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`. You then use PHP's `strtotime` to convert to a UNIX timestamp, then `date` to output it in the format of your choice (something like `d/M/Y` for "1/Mar/2013")

Comment: Ok, So may i put strtotime after the date eg DATE strtotime or?

Comment: I said ***PHP's*** `strtotime`. That means you call [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) in *PHP*...

Answer (score 0):

You only need one `DATE` column in your table to store the century+year, month and day components.

To extract those components into separate columns,

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(mydatecol,'%M') AS month_name
     , DATE_FORMAT(mydatecol,'%e') AS day_of_month
     , DATE_FORMAT(mydatecol,'%Y') AS year
  FROM ...
```

To insert a date value

```
INSERT INTO ... (..., mydatecol, ... ) VALUES (... ,'2013-03-01', ... )
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format